# Access to a simple API with Python

Tags: python, api, curl, urllib2, pycurl

I have a simple api endpoint:

```
http://example.de/create.json
```

I need to send the following via POST:

-text

-url

-username

The curl command for this task looks like this:

```
curl --data-urlencode "text=Beispieltext" -d "url=http://google.de" -d "username=User1" http://example.de/create.json
```

I want to implement this in my code. I want to submit data to the api and work with the answer from the api.
Actually I have no idea where to start. I read and tried a lot about Pycurl, urllib2 and subprocess but now I don't understand anything anymore :D

How would you do that?
I need help, I don't know where to start!

Comment: [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is my favourite library for curl-like calls

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple.  Should be something like:

```
import pycurl
import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://example.de/create.json')
output = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, output.write)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'your post data')
c.perform()
```

Result is in output.getvalue().  Don't forget to output.close() when done.

Comment: How can I define my post data?

e.g. c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'text='+mytext) does not work!
How can I use variables in it?